# In Xcode is there code that will open up the console for you?

Tags: xcode, console

Is there a way in Xcode to have your software open up the console for you?  I would like to have it when my code compiles and runs in Debug to have the console open up automatically but in release for it to not open.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to achieve this is :

1. Open a new tab, and rename it 'Console' (or what name you want)
2. In this tab, show only the panes you want (in your case the console)
3. Go to Preferences>Behaviors
4. Tell Xcode to 'Show tab' and give it the name you set in 1. (you can set this at various moments, when build starts, or when app runs).

Now, each you will either compile or run your app, Xcode will switch to the tab you have set in Prefs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I would like the console to also up open when I open a debug build version of my .app bundle, so without Xcode running the app.  Is there a set of functions that can open the console window?

Comment: no sorry I don't think so, unless you write a foundation tool that run in a terminal

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  That's a shame.  I am just trying to make things cross platform between the mac and windows.  Windows does it pretty easily.  Oh well.

Comment: You are welcome Michael.I think there is an alternative. You can try outputing using the `NSLog()` function. The result should be seen using the 'Console' app and, in the 'Files' group you should see an item called 'Library log', where there are all logs for each app.

Answer (score 0):

You dont use code, you go to xcode pref's and do it there

Answer (score 0):

This is where I came for the answer given and marked correct (although it's not clear it was what the asker quite wanted).

Arguably, a simpler version of the answer given is to set the Behaviors preferences to show the Debugger when a run starts. With the settings in the image below, this opens up the console (or the console + variable views or the variables view, depending on how it was last set - that's what 'Current Views' means).

[image: Xcode Behavior settings]